# C: Array of memory addresses?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a sort of container for multiple different structs. Unfortunately C only allows type specific arrays, meaning I'd have to make a different array for each type of struct.

The current solution I came up with is a container that holds memory addresses. This way the program can just pass the memory address of one of the elements to a function.

Currently the only code I have is a failed attempt using void pointers (not really familiar with pointers and memory addresses yet unfortunately)

The following is my test code I was writing to try and understand how this stuff works:

```
void* arr[10]={};
int len=0;

int n[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) { //add pointers nums in n to arr
  arr[i]=(void*)(&n[i]);
  len++;
}

for (int i=0;i<len;i++) { //print contents of arr
  printf("%p\n", (void*)arr[i]);
  printf("\t%d\n", arr[i]); //trying to print actual value (eg. 2 for index 2) but not really sure how to...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `arr[i]` already is of type `void *`, you don't need to cast it. And that should also give a hind about the problem of printing the value (you print the *pointer* and not whatever it might point to).

Comment: If you want an array that can contain objects of a specific, enumerable set of types, then you could consider declaring a `union` type that has a member for each of those types, and create an array of those unions.  But that does not by itself solve the problem of knowing which member of each union is the one containing the value.

Comment: Well written question, good sample code. Suggested improvement would be to be more specific with the issue. Why is it a "failed attempt"? Does it not compile (show error), does not output what you expect (show the output and what you expect instead), etc. This will invite more useful answers as well as help others with similar questions.

Comment: OT: non of the `(void*)` are needed

Comment: The way [qsort](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/qsort.html) does it is it accepts a function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but there is some stuff missing...

In C any object pointer can be converted to a void-pointer and back to a pointer of the original type. So an int-pointer can be converted to a void-pointer an back to an int-pointer. And a float-pointer can be converted to a void-pointer an back to an float-pointer.

So using an array of void-pointers to store pointers to different object types is a fine approach.

But... in order to convert the void-pointer back to the original type, you need to know what the original type was. If you just saves the void-pointer, you don't have that information.

Instead consider something like:

```
struct gp
{
    void* p;
    unsigned type_tag;
}

#define INT_TYPE 0
#define FLOAT_TYPE 1
```

and use it like:

```
struct gp arr[2];
int n = 42;
float f = 42.42;

arr[0].p = &n;
arr[0].type_tag = INT_TYPE;

arr[1].p = &f;
arr[1].type_tag = FLOAT_TYPE;

for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    if (arr[i].type_tag == INT_TYPE)
    {
        int* p = (int*)arr[i].p;  // Cast void-pointer back to int-pointer
        printf("%d\n", *p);       // Get int-value using *p, i.e. dereference the pointer
    }
    else if (arr[i].type_tag == FLOAT_TYPE)
    {
        int* p = (float*)arr[i].p;  // Cast void-pointer back to float-pointer
        printf("%f\n", *p);         // Get float-value using *p, i.e. dereference the pointer
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid having to use ifs or switches to check the type_tag?

Comment: @xcdev No, not in the general case.... but for instance for printing, you could make an array of function pointers and use type_tag as index

Comment: I think making a separate function to do the casting will suffice for now.

Comment: @4386427: you gave a good answer based on what the OP told you.  But if you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876657/), you'll see the OP really needs to read up on [C unions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm), [switch statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm), and [enums](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/enum-in-c), among other things.

Comment: @paulsm4 hmm... well, seems OP took these ideas and ran into new problems. To me that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to derefence the pointer stored in the array. You also need to cast it to the original type of the referenced objects.

```
    printf("\t%d\n", *(int *)arr[i]);
```

Comment: In the case that the memory addresses are refer to different types (eg. two different structs) how would I cast it to the original type without actually knowing the original type?

Comment: @xcdev you can't know what type a void pointer points to. You need to store that information somehow.