# C: Reading property of struct pointer causes property to change?

Tags: c

I have a program that stores two different structs (`tri` & `quad`) in an array of a special struct defined below:

```
struct inst_ptr
{
  void* p;
  unsigned type;
};
```

The structs `tri` & `quad` have a `superbase` property

The following code displays how the structs are defined:

```
struct inst
{
  char name[50];
  int id;
};

struct tri
{
  struct inst superbase;
};
struct quad
{
  struct inst superbase;
};
```

Function for creating new instances (all located outside of `main`):

```
struct inst_ptr insts[100]; //instance container
int cinsts=0; //instance count

int inst_new(int type)
{
  switch(type)
  {
    case TYPE_TRI:
        {
            struct tri i;
            insts[cinsts].p=&i;
        }
    case TYPE_QUAD:
        {
            struct quad i;
            insts[cinsts].p=&i;
        }
  }

  insts[cinsts].type=type;
  cinsts++;

  return cinsts-1; //return index of instance in array
}
```

In my `main` function I create a sample tri, writing and reading it's values:

```
struct tri* t1=(struct tri*)insts[inst_new(TYPE_TRI)].p;
strcpy(t1->superbase.name, "tri1");
t1->superbase.id=70;
printf("id: %d\n", t1->superbase.id);
printf("id: %d\n", t1->superbase.id); <- problem occurs here and onward
```

Printing the id the first time works, printing 70 in the output. However, the second time it prints a long random integer.

Output:

```
id: 69
id: 1973802146
id: 1973802146
```

As you shown above, after the second read it keeps printing `1973802146`. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong but I have a feeling I'm missing an extremely basic concept relating to pointers and structs.

Comment: Storing pointers to temporary variables = _undefined behavior_ `struct tri i; insts[cinsts].p=&i;`

Comment: You need to allocate the structs dynamically with `malloc()`, not put pointers to local variables in a global array.

Comment: This is Evil: `struct tri i; insts[cinsts].p=&i;`.  "i" becomes *undefined* when you exit inst_new().  Hence, accessing `insts[i].p`  anytime thereafter is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I knew it was something fundamental I was clearly missing.

Comment: You might also want to learn about C [_unions_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union).

Comment: The code `{ struct tri i; insts[cinsts].p=&i; }` will assign the address of a local variable, normally located on the stack, to the array element. This address is no longer valid when the block is left, so this is undefined behavior, but you may not notice the problem immediately. For the 1st `printf`, the code accesses the invalid address and reads the old value before calling `printf`. The `printf` call then will use some stack, which in your case seems to overwrite the memory. The 2nd `printf` again reads the invalid address which now contains some data resulting from the 1st `printf`

Comment: Read up a bit about `switch`, `case` and `break`, so that you understand that your code does not work as you intended it to.

Comment: See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621027/writing-a-generic-struct-print-method-in-c/65621483#65621483 It shows/discusses the various ways to do what you're trying to do: switch on type, virtual function table, etc. and ways to organize the structs.

Comment: C doesn't use the word "property" for this; `superbase` is a **member** of `struct tri` and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the address of local variables in the array. That's bad because those variables doesn't exist once the function returns. You should use dynamic allocation instead.

Besides that you `switch` need `break` statements. And perhaps also a `default` case.

Like:

```
int inst_new(int type)
{
  switch(type)
  {
    case TYPE_TRI:
        {
            struct tri *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
            if (p == NULL) exit(1);
            insts[cinsts].p=p;
            break;
        }
    case TYPE_QUAD:
        {
            struct quad *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
            if (p == NULL) exit(1);
            insts[cinsts].p=p;
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            // Unknown type.. add error handling here
            exit(1);
        }
  }

  insts[cinsts].type=type;
  cinsts++;

  return cinsts-1; //return index of instance in array
}
```

As an alternative you can do:

```
int inst_new(int type)
{
  insts[cinsts].p = NULL

  switch(type)
  {
    case TYPE_TRI:
        {
            insts[cinsts].p=malloc(sizeof(struct tri));
            break;
        }
    case TYPE_QUAD:
        {
            insts[cinsts].p=malloc(sizeof(struct quad));
            break;
        }
  }

  if (insts[cinsts].p == NULL) exit(1);  // malloc failed
  insts[cinsts].type=type;
  cinsts++;

  return cinsts-1; //return index of instance in array
}
```